# FullCalendar 2.3.0 Change day colour on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to change the day background colour on mouse hover.

The hover event needs to be captured on `.fc-bg .fc-day` and `.fc-content-skeleton .fc-day-number` for this purpose. This works ok until I use [background render events](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events/) as allDay events, because then there is a third layer with class `.fc-bg-event-skeleton` which is lying on top of the other two layers. The events of the underlying elements are not fired anymore and because cells are rendered using a colspan I cannot highlight just one day if there are background render events in a row.

Is there any possibility to highlight days on mouseover in fullcalendar? I'm using the month view.

```
<div class="fc-bg">...</div>
<div class="fc-content-skeleton">...</div>
<div class="fc-bgevent-skeleton">
    <table><tbody>
        <tr>
             <td class="fc-week-number" style="width:21px"></td>
             <td colspan="3"></td>
             <td colspan="1" class="fc-bgevent available"></td>
             <td colspan="3"></td>
        </tr>
   </tbody></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 19):

Your best bet is to use `pointer-events:none` to allow the hover to pass through certain container elements and `pointer-events:auto` to re-enable it on child elements that still need pointer events.

```css
.fc-day:hover{
    background:lightblue;
}

/*Allow pointer-events through*/
.fc-slats, /*horizontals*/
.fc-content-skeleton, /*day numbers*/
.fc-bgevent-skeleton /*events container*/{
    pointer-events:none
}

/*Turn pointer events back on*/
.fc-bgevent,
.fc-event-container{
    pointer-events:auto; /*events*/
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slicedtoad/djr6bhk8/2/)

Unless this causes a specific unsolvable problem for you, this is the best way. You could mess with z-index, transparent-overlays or a lot of JS but this solution causes the least headaches by far.

Comment: I'm sorry, I just added the information that I'm using allDay events as background events (in month view). In this case your example doesn't work. Additionally it's no option to disallow all pointer-events just to be able to highlight a day when hovering over the month number headline and events.

Comment: @chmielot Updated. Is there a specific reason you don't like disallowing pointer-events? You can turn them back on as needed.

Comment: I am using 'normal' events, too. These normal events should open a tooltip on mouse hover and you should be able to click on them for additional action. After disabling pointer-events this doesn't work anymore. I understand that disabling pointer events obviously allows the div's in the background to "shine through" for :hover in the table row with the background-render events.

Comment: @chmielot When you hover over an event, should it still highlight that day? Or just show the tooltip?

Comment: @chmielot The fiddle has working tooltips now for regular events. Adding them for background events is trivial.

Comment: @slicedtoad Is there a way I can hover a cell in Agendaweek view.   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34917919/how-to-style-daymouseover-in-fullcalender