# how to style dayMouseover in Fullcalender

Tags: html, css, angularjs, fullcalendar

I am using Fullcalender plugin in my Angular application. I want to change cell color when i mouse over a time slot (eg. 7.30am-8.00am) in AgendaWeek view.I want something like this:

[image]

I have tried changing css :
 `.fc-widget-content:hover { 
    background: #adf4fa;
}`
but it doesn't work for cell.It changes entire row color.

Comment: Hi, how did you get alternate row color for columns?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can edit the background color of only one cell because the cells aren't actually cells but rows:

```
<tr data-time="11:30:00" class="fc-minor">
    <td class="fc-axis fc-time fc-widget-content" style="width: 51px;"></td>
    <td class="fc-widget-content"></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure must be in table tag and if you have this `.fc-widget-content` parent class, you can use like 
`.fc-widget-content table tr td:hover 
{ 
background: #adf4fa; 
}`