# FullCalendar hover day with events jQuery dayMouseover() and dayMouseout()

Tags: jquery, css, fullcalendar, mouseover, jquery-hover

i have a problem with hovering my days. If i have empty day hover is good but if i have one or more events then the problem arises. 
I wish my calendar nicely would highlight days. Maybe like this:
http://gloriatheme.com/demo/wp/vintauge/events/
Maybe is a function in fullcalendar for hovering all day with events 
as in Example?
Now i have this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TgLzp.png)

I can't found function in fullcalendar doc.

Comment: post some relevant code demonstrating the issue please, otherwise we are mostly just guessing. It's also a little unclear exactly which things you want to highlight - please clarify, and the screenshot does not really explain either.

Comment: Please check if this will solve your issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28864391/fullcalendar-2-3-0-change-day-colour-on-hover

Comment: i would like this highlight: http://gloriatheme.com/demo/wp/vintauge/events/ . Hightlight all day with event. something like dayMOuseover? this is not clarify? screenshot is for show what i have now.

Comment: you mean you want the pink highlight on the current day? Or you want it to open a popup when you hover over a specific event? You've said you've made some code which doesn't quite do what you want. Post the code, explain where it fails, and we can try and help you fix it. That's how it works on SO - people generally don't just write you a whole example code from nothing, they help you to fix your own attempt.